# Javascript error in jssh in Firefox 4.0b1

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, nserror, jssh

Using this Javascript through jssh compiled and built for the new Firefox 4.0 beta 1 returns an odd message. Here is the code (sorry if it's a little messy).

In summary the code checks all frames of a Firefox window which is a test page of our unit tests for a `<td>` element that has an `onclick` which contains the phrase Goodbye Wonderful, instead of getting a failed response back we are receiving this odd nserror at the end which we cannot explain.

```
var firefoxWindow = getWindows()[0];
var browser = firefoxWindow.getBrowser();
var doc = browser.contentDocument;


var elem = null;
var elems = doc.getElementsByTagName('td');

for(a=0;a < elems.length;a++){ if( ((elems[a] !== null && elems[a].hasAttributes() === true && elems[a].getAttribute('onclick') !== null && elems[a].getAttribute('onclick').toString().match(/doNothing/gim) !== null && elems[a].getAttribute('onclick').toString().match(/Goodbye Wonderful/gim).length >= 0) || (elems[a] !== null && elems[a].onclick !== null && elems[a].onclick.toString().match(/Goodbye Wonderful/gim) !== null && elems[a].onclick.toString().match(/Goodbye Wonderful/gim).length >= 0))) { elem = elems[a]; } }

var found = false;
var window = null; 

for(var i=0; i < firefoxWindow.frames.length; i++){if(firefoxWindow.frames[i].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('object window') > -1){window = firefoxWindow.frames[i]; break;}}


function recursiveSearch(frames){ for(var i=0; i<frames.length; i++){var elems = frames[i].document.getElementsByTagName('td'); for(a=0;a < elems.length;a++){ if( ((elems[a] !== null && elems[a].hasAttributes() === true && elems[a].getAttribute('onclick') !== null && elems[a].getAttribute('onclick').toString().match(/Goodbye Wonderful/gim) !== null && elems[a].getAttribute('onclick').toString().match(/Goodbye Wonderful/gim).length >= 0) || (elems[a] !== null && elems[a].onclick !== null && elems[a].onclick.toString().match(/Goodbye Wonderful/gim) !== null && elems[a].onclick.toString().match(/Goodbye Wonderful/gim).length >= 0))) { elem = elems[a]; } } if(elem){found = true; return;} else{ if(frames[i].frames.length>0){recursiveSearch(frames[i].frames);}}}}if(!elem && window.frames.length > 0){ recursiveSearch(window.frames); }var origColor = '';if(elem !== null){origColor = elem.style.backgroundColor;if(origColor === null){origColor = '';} elem.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';}
```

Here is the return message from jssh :

> Received: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: interactive :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 1"  data: no]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSSh is no longer supported in Firefox 4 and is a mess to handle, switching to mozrepl since it's written mostly in javascript and adding my own javascript commands directly to the extension seems to be a better way of accomplishing certain things.